# why oauth 2.0 client id expired automatically?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-identity

Execute compute engine

```
api(GET https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/zones/{zone}/instances/{resourceId}) with oauth 2.0 client id.
```

I created an OAuth2.0 client ID and got access_token and refresh_token based on the steps on this site.

[Obtaining OAuth 2.0 access tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#obtainingaccesstokens)

[Refreshing an access token (offline access)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline)

I can execute api with access_token which was refreshed.

after 3days, run this step again,

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline

response was

```
json
{   "error": "invalid_grant",   "error_description": "Token has been expired or revoked." }
```

why expired refresh_token?

> refresh_token
> A token that you can use to obtain a new access token. Refresh tokens are valid until the user revokes access. Again, this field is only present in this response if you set the access_type parameter to offline in the initial request to Google's authorization server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things which can cause a refresh token to expire.

1. you are using a gmail scope and the user changed their password.
2. it has not been used in six months.
3. the user has revoked your access in their google account.
4. If the user runs your app you get a refresh token, if they run it again you get a different refresh token, you can do this up to 50 times and get new refresh tokens and they will all work after number 50 the first one will expire.  Make sure you are always saving the most resent refresh token.
5. your app is currently in testing and has not been set to published and has not been though the verification process.

Documentation link for [expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

Comment: My app gets a refresh token once and keeps using that refresh token. So you don't know that the first refresh token has expired.

> The app is currently being tested, is not set to public, and has not completed the validation process.

Is there a reference that mentions this? Could not find it.

Comment: Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent? check the consent screen.  Is your project in testing? has it been verified?  Recently it seams that projects in testing have their refresh tokens expired more often then they used to.

Comment: My app is being tested. And that was exactly what you answered. "Test user approval expires in 7 days from the date of consent."
https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615/setting-up-your-oauth-consent-screen#user-type zippy =% 2

Thank you +1+

Comment: This may then be the cause of your refresh token expiring.